# Grep sorting dates

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Each day I have to manually identify each stuck call by looking for calls with a date older than the current day. I have managed to grep the required fields to identify the calls in question.

```
grep -e start -e instance stuckcdr.txt


CDR instance 153 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:09:968]
CDR instance 200 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:56:991]
CDR instance 209 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:55:55:358]
CDR instance 216 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:40:443]
CDR instance 218 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:44:084]
CDR instance 221 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:08:11:690]
CDR instance 222 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:52:47:846]
CDR instance 223 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:03:858]
CDR instance 225 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:02:40:345]
CDR instance 226 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:58:530]
CDR instance 227 [] > :
                start                    [03:04:2022][17:53:16:771]
CDR instance 231 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:06:19:830]
CDR instance 234 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:06:06:937]
CDR instance 237 [] > :
                start                    [04:04:2022][08:55:03:575]
CDR instance 238 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:15:537]
CDR instance 242 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:18:753]
CDR instance 243 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:23:38:303]
CDR instance 244 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:01:40:195]
CDR instance 245 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:08:33:821]
CDR instance 246 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:53:03:281]
CDR instance 247 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:42:06:561]
CDR instance 248 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:04:49:953]
CDR instance 249 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:29:250]
CDR instance 250 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:01:33:905]
CDR instance 253 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:55:48:996]
CDR instance 254 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:27:55:402]
CDR instance 255 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:04:38:088]
CDR instance 256 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:42:47:932]
CDR instance 258 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:57:16:372]
CDR instance 259 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:46:35:323]
CDR instance 260 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:19:144]
CDR instance 262 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:52:56:531]
CDR instance 263 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:50:331]
```

Can I also filter the data by start date older than the current date?

It would massively speed up the process :)

Thanks

Comment: Ping: I posted a revised solution, which addresses the issue brought up in the comments for my accepted answer. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

Edit: This only works if the date units are ordered largest to smallest (eg. `%Y:%m:%d`). That's not the case with OP's data. See the comments and revised solution below.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v date="$(date '+[%d:%m:%Y][00:00:00:000]')" '
$2=="instance"{instance=$0}
$1=="start" && $2<date {$1=$1; print instance,$0}' stuckcdr.txt
```

This prints entries from before the start of the current day.

We use lexical sorting to compare date strings. This is possible due to each field (month, hour, etc) being the same length. `LC_ALL=C` guarantees consistent behaviour in different locales.

To print entries older than 'now' (when the script is run, to the nearest second, as opposed to older than 'today'), use this date syntax: `date="$(date '+[%d:%m:%Y][%H:%M:%S:000]')"`.

`$1=$1` just trims the whitespace. I also print instance number and date on the same line, for readability.

Example output:

```
CDR instance 223 [] > : start [07:04:2022][12:28:03:858]
CDR instance 227 [] > : start [03:04:2022][17:53:16:771]
CDR instance 237 [] > : start [04:04:2022][08:55:03:575]
CDR instance 238 [] > : start [07:04:2022][12:28:15:537]
CDR instance 243 [] > : start [07:04:2022][12:23:38:303]
CDR instance 254 [] > : start [07:04:2022][12:27:55:402]
```

You can also sort output by piping to `sort -k 8,8` (sort by date) or `sort -n 3,3` (sort by instance number).

Edit:

As tshiono noted in a comment, the date is in the wrong format to be compared directly. This revised solution splits and rearranges the date for a correct comparison.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v date="$(date '+[%Y:%m:%d][00:00:00:000]')" '
$2=="instance"{instance=$0}
$1=="start" && split($2, a, /[]:[]+/) &&
date>"["a[4]":"a[3]":"a[2]"]["a[5]":"a[6]":"a[7]"]" {
    $1=$1
    print instance,$0
}
' stuckcdr.txt
```

Comment: With your comparison method, `[01:04:2022]` (Apr 1st) is judged to be *older than* `[31:03:2022]` (Mar 31st), isn't it?

Comment: @tshioni Woops, you are 100% right. The date format in the data is arranged smallest to largest units, but it must be arranged largest to smallest units for comparison to work. (Ie. it would work for `[%Y:%m:%d]`). The example only works because all the input dates happen to be the same month and year.

Comment: The date can be re-arranged for comparison (largest to smallest), or maybe separately compare year, month, day, and time in the right order. I will post an edit when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get closer by asking grep to exclude lines that match today's date; this assumes you don't have any records for *future* timestamps!

```sh
grep -e start -e instance stuckcdr.txt | grep -v "$(date +'%d:%m:%Y')"
```

This will leave the "instance" lines behind (that correspond to today), but it should be visually easier to find the historic dates & data.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the combination of `GNU sed`, `sort` and other commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%F)
sed -E '/^CDR/N;s/\n//' input_file.txt | sed -E 's/(^[^][]+\[][^][]+\[([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{4}).*)/\4-\3-\2\t\1/' | sort -k1,1 | sed "/^$today/{d;q}" | cut -f2- | sed 's/> :/\n/'
```

Result:

```
CDR instance 227 [] 
                start                    [03:04:2022][17:53:16:771]
CDR instance 237 [] 
                start                    [04:04:2022][08:55:03:575]
CDR instance 223 [] 
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:03:858]
CDR instance 238 [] 
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:15:537]
CDR instance 243 [] 
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:23:38:303]
CDR instance 254 [] 
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:27:55:402]
```

- First assign `today` to the today's string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- `sed -E '/^CDR/N;s/\n//'` merges two lines to make the sort easy.
- `sed -E 's/(^[^][]+\[][^][]+\[([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{4}).*)/\4-\3-\2\t\1/'` extracts the date field, then prepend the date string to the line
  rearranging the format to `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- `sort -k1,1` sorts the lines by date, older first, newer last.
- `sed "/^$today/{d;q}"` prints the lines older than today, exclusive.
- `cut -f2-` removes the date field preceding the line.
- `sed 's/> :/\n/'` splits the line into original two lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge each 2 lines into 1 line by `paste`.
2. Filter lines by `awk`.
3. Split each 1 line into 2 lines by `tr`.

This technique is also called Schwartzian transform

```
λ cat input.txt
CDR instance 153 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:09:968]
CDR instance 200 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:56:991]
CDR instance 209 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:55:55:358]
CDR instance 216 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:40:443]
CDR instance 218 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:44:084]
CDR instance 221 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:08:11:690]
CDR instance 222 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:52:47:846]
CDR instance 223 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:03:858]
CDR instance 225 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:02:40:345]
CDR instance 226 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:58:530]
CDR instance 227 [] > :
                start                    [03:04:2022][17:53:16:771]
CDR instance 231 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:06:19:830]
CDR instance 234 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:06:06:937]
CDR instance 237 [] > :
                start                    [04:04:2022][08:55:03:575]
CDR instance 238 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:15:537]
CDR instance 242 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:18:753]
CDR instance 243 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:23:38:303]
CDR instance 244 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:01:40:195]
CDR instance 245 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:08:33:821]
CDR instance 246 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:53:03:281]
CDR instance 247 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:42:06:561]
CDR instance 248 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:04:49:953]
CDR instance 249 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:29:250]
CDR instance 250 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:01:33:905]
CDR instance 253 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:55:48:996]
CDR instance 254 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:27:55:402]
CDR instance 255 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:04:38:088]
CDR instance 256 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:42:47:932]
CDR instance 258 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:57:16:372]
CDR instance 259 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:46:35:323]
CDR instance 260 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:05:19:144]
CDR instance 262 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][09:52:56:531]
CDR instance 263 [] > :
                start                    [12:04:2022][10:07:50:331]
```

```sh
paste -sd '\t\n' input.txt |
  awk -v today=20220408 -F : '{ len=length($0); split(substr($0, len-24, 10),a,":") } today > a[3] a[2] a[1]' |
  tr '\t' '\n'
```

```
CDR instance 223 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:03:858]
CDR instance 227 [] > :
                start                    [03:04:2022][17:53:16:771]
CDR instance 237 [] > :
                start                    [04:04:2022][08:55:03:575]
CDR instance 238 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:28:15:537]
CDR instance 243 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:23:38:303]
CDR instance 254 [] > :
                start                    [07:04:2022][12:27:55:402]
```

To filter the data by start date older than the current date, use `awk -v today=$(date +%Y%m%d)` to get the system time.